# Privileges thorugh python proccess.popen function in Winows 10, in same power shell session

Tags: python, windows, powershell, popen, privileges

I am trying to copy some registers from windows 10 in a output folder but it gives me a permission error because the SeBackupPrivilege are not enabled by default.

I am trying to call a dll from my python script with proccess.popen function.
This dll:
https://github.com/giuliano108/SeBackupPrivilege

The problem is that it seems that the python script runs the command "Set-SeBackupPrivilege" from the dll in another power shell sessio, therefore the privileges are not setted for the current session and I cannot retrive some files from the Windows 10 system, as registry files.

Here my function code to get privileges:

```
def GetSeBackupPrivilegesFunc():
    """GetSeBackupPrivilegesFunc runs external dll scripts in order to obtain SeBackUpPrivileges in the running power shell console and thus allow the copy of some files as the windows register files
    whoami /priv | findstr Backup
        Returns the privileges
    """

    global gl_utilsFolderPath, gl_utilSeBackupPrivilege

    pathAbsAux = os.path.abspath(gl_utilsFolderPath)
    print("DEBUG - pathAbsAux", pathAbsAux)

    #Run Get-ChildItem . | Unblock-File
    auxDir = os.path.join(pathAbsAux, gl_utilSeBackupPrivilege)

    if(os.path.exists(auxDir) == False):
        print("The path auxDir ", auxDir, "  does NOT exist")
        return False

    commandAux = "Get-ChildItem " + auxDir + " | Unblock-File"
    print("DEBUG - Command Shell 1 = ",commandAux)
    outputCommand = runPowerShellInside(commandAux)
    print("outputCommand = ", outputCommand)

    #Run Import-Module .\SeBackupPrivilegeUtils.dll
    auxDir = os.path.join(pathAbsAux, gl_utilSeBackupPrivilege)
    auxDir = auxDir + "\\SeBackupPrivilegeUtils.dll"
    if(os.path.exists(auxDir) == False):
        print("The path auxDir ", auxDir, "  does NOT exist")
        return False
    commandAux = "Import-Module " + auxDir
    print("DEBUG - Command Shell 1 = ",commandAux)
    outputCommand = runPowerShellInside(commandAux)
    print("outputCommand = ", outputCommand)

    #Run  Import-Module .\SeBackupPrivilegeCmdLets.dll
    auxDir = os.path.join(pathAbsAux, gl_utilSeBackupPrivilege)
    auxDir = auxDir + "\\SeBackupPrivilegeCmdLets.dll"
    if(os.path.exists(auxDir) == False):
        print("The path auxDir ", auxDir, "  does NOT exist")
        return False
    commandAux = "Import-Module " + auxDir
    print("DEBUG - Command Shell 1 = ",commandAux)
    outputCommand = runPowerShellInside(commandAux)
    print("outputCommand = ", outputCommand)

    #Run  Set-SeBackupPrivilege
    commandAux =  "Set-SeBackupPrivilege"
    outputCommand = runPowerShellInside(commandAux)
    print("outputCommand = ", outputCommand)

    #It should have work, therefore return true
    #ToDo Check in a perfect way 100% sure and not 60% sure that this methode has work
    return True
```

Here the function which runs the commands:

```
def runPowerShellInside(cmd):
    #comandPowerOuptut = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
    OutAux = ""
    ErrAux = ""

    comandPowerOuptut = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
    #comandPowerOuptut = subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", cmd], capture_output=True)
```

I was wondering if there is an option for Popen to run the commands in the same power shell session that calls the python script.
I have thought about making a power shell script that first sets the environment and after calls the python script, however I would need to pass the arguments from the shell script call to the python script call inside the script and I am a little bit lazy to do so.
Another option would be to run first the power shell script and after the python script separately. I have already programmed a power shell script that does so as plan B, but I would like to have it all together in the python script.

That's why I wonder if there is any option for popen to run in the same power shell session in order to set the privileges for the whole run cycle of the python script. Or there is another way achieve the goal just with python.

Thank you for your time.

I tried with process.popen function and the commands in the power shell, the commands seem to work fine, but the privileges seems given to another instance of power shell.